# Use static image as a world map in java-script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

I am trying to render an image like below and want it to act like the world map.[image: Geology.com]

I want to create a javascript function which shows location dynamically into the image when I pass (latitude, longitude) pair.

I have tried google map API documented in "developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/…". But the problem is that image is not in that projection type. So results are so different than expected.

Comment: What was the solution you have tried??

Comment: I have tried google map API documented in "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple " . But the problem is that image is not in that projection type. So results are so different than expected.

Comment: it looks like the image just uses a cartesian lat-lon coord system with (0,0) at the center of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image appears to use a plate carreé projection, which is commonly used for raster data sets of the world. This projection easily allows reprojection - and as rioV8 suggests, simply maps longitude and latitude as though they were x,y coordinates on a Cartesian plane rather than a spheroid.

The image you have shared is twice as wide as high, which also helps confirm a plate carreé: if the projection maps longitude and latitude as Cartesian coordinates the image should be twice as wide as high (360 degrees around, 180 degrees pole to pole).

Now we need to make a projection for this (not particularly difficult) or we could use a d3 projection: `d3.geoEquirectangular()` (plate carreé goes by a few names).

I'll just go over the d3 method here, if using the d3 projection, we need to understand the scale of the projection. The default value takes 2π radians and maps it to 960 pixels, which gives us a scale of: 960/2π. If we want to wrap 2π radians to an arbitrary image width we use a scale of width/2π.

So we could project points relative to this image with:

```
d3.geoEquirectangular()
  .scale(width/Math.PI/2)
  .translate([width/2,height/2]) // image width/height so [0,0] is centered
```

```js
var width =400;
var height = 200;


var projection = d3.geoEquirectangular()
 .scale(width/Math.PI/2) 
 .translate([width/2,height/2]);
      
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("fill","yellow")
  .attr("transform", "translate("+projection([79.842778,6.934444])+")")
```

```css
img, svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p3MK.jpg" width="400" height="200"/>
  <svg width="1958" height="929"></svg>
</div>
```

Of course once we know the projection, we could reproject the original raster image ([eg.](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4329423)), and project points onto that.